# How to resolve "exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info" error while using pip install package_name?

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, conda, annoy

I am unable to install any package out of `scann, lshash, annoy` etc using `pip install` on my `Windows 10` using `conda` environment. Surprisingly, when I used `pip install autocorrect`, it was installed. I am getting the error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                                                           command: 'c:\users\admin\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btjh444k\lshash_e1892c63618846ad8854e50ef0d165c7\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btjh444k\lshash_e1892c63618846ad8854e50ef0d165c7\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-n1j15tcy'                                                                                                                                 cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btjh444k\lshash_e1892c63618846ad8854e50ef0d165c7\               Complete output (7 lines):                                                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "", line 1, in                                                                                     File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btjh444k\lshash_e1892c63618846ad8854e50ef0d165c7\setup.py", line 3, in                                                                                                                import lshash                                                                                                         File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btjh444k\lshash_e1892c63618846ad8854e50ef0d165c7\lshash_*init*_.py", line 12, in                                                                                                     from lshash import LSHash                                                                                           ImportError: cannot import name 'LSHash' from partially initialized module 'lshash' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btjh444k\lshash_e1892c63618846ad8854e50ef0d165c7\lshash_*init*_.py)                                                                                                                          ----------------------------------------                                                                            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

I have installed `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015` also. I am using `Windows 10`

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of the error message?

Comment: Looks like the `setup.py` of `lshash` might be broken. You might want to contact its authors/maintainers and report this as a bug (maybe?).